# OpenCL user defined inline functions

Tags: c, opencl

Is it possible to define my own functions in OpenCL code, in order that the kernels could call them? It yes, where can I see some simple example?

Comment: Old question...anything else you need from an answer?

Comment: Seems like the title and the question are different?  Title specifically asks for `inline`, whereas question just asks if we can define our our functions...

Answer (score 14):

Function used to create program is ...

```
cl_program clCreateProgramWithSource  (     
    cl_context context,
    cl_uint count,
    const char **strings,
    const size_t *lengths,
    cl_int *errcode_ret)
```

You can place functions inside the **strings** parameter like this,

```
float AddVector(float a, float b)
{
    return a + b;
}

kernel void VectorAdd(
    global read_only float* a,
    global read_only float* b,
    global write_only float* c )
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    //c[index] = a[index] + b[index];
    c[index] = AddVector(a[index], b[index]);
}
```

Now you have one user defined function "AddVector" and a kernel function "VectorAdd"

Answer (score 5):

Based on the code samples [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/sdk/website/OpenCL/website/samples.html) you can just write functions like:

```
inline int add(int a,int b)
{
   return a+b;
}
```

(Eg. look at the .cl file in the DXTC or bitonic sort examples.)

I don't know if that's an nvidia only extension but the OpenCL documentation talks about "auxiliary functions" as well as kernels.

Comment: Strange, the OpenCL spec doesn't say anything about __device

Comment: Yes. I'm wondering if I misremembered. Or if Apple added it as an extension. So if you modded me up, mod me down again until it's tested :-)

Comment: Or...if I'm confusing with CUDA code. I've been playing with both.

Answer (score 3):

OpenCL supports auxiliary functions. See page 19 of [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120125075933/http://www.hotchips.org/archives/hc21/1_sun/HC21.23.2.OpenCLTutorial-Epub/HC21.23.230.Houston-AMD-AMD-and-OpenCL.pdf) for examples.

Comment: Oooh,.. there's a lot of useful information on a good baseline card there. nice.

Comment: new link dead too :-P

Answer (score 2):

I googled around a bit, and just kept coming back to this question :-P

In the end, what I did was use macros, since inlining would be implementation-dependent anyway, and macros don't seem to have any major disadvantage in the context of c99 OpenCL programs? eg:

```
#define getFilterBoardOffset( filter, inputPlane ) \
    ( ( filter * gInputPlanes + inputPlane ) * gFilterSizeSquared )
#define getResultBoardOffset( n, filter ) \
    ( ( n * gNumFilters + filter ) * gOutputBoardSizeSquared )
```

instead of:

```
inline float getFilterBoardOffset( float filter, int inputPlane ) { 
    return ( filter * gInputPlanes + inputPlane ) * gFilterSizeSquared; 
}
inline float getResultBoardOffset( float n, int filter ) { 
    return ( n * gNumFilters + filter ) * gOutputBoardSizeSquared; 
}
```