# How to define functions in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

How do i define functions in OpenCL? I tried to build one program for each function. And it didn't worked.

```
float AddVectors(float a, float b)
{
    return a + b;
}

kernel void VectorAdd(
    global read_only float* a,
    global read_only float* b,
    global write_only float* c )
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    //c[index] = a[index] + b[index];
    c[index] = AddVectors(a[index], b[index]);
}
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924619/opencl-user-defined-inline-functions ?

Comment: yep, searched but didnt find that before.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create one program for each function, instead you create a program for a set of functions that are marked with `__kernel` (or `kernel`) and potentially auxiliary functions (like your `AddVectors` function) using for example `clCreateProgramWithSource` call.

Check out basic tutorials from Apple, AMD, NVIDIA..

Comment: I just tested this. Did not receive any errors so It may be working. Also just found out that clBuildProgram is not threadsafe. So we are putting all programs in a single cl file for a reason.