# Why is execute system command not allowed in GPU code?

Tags: c++, opencl

I tried to execute system command in GPU code (OpenCL/C++ kernel) like this

```
system("ngspice");
```

but I have got this ERROR message:  CL_INVALID_BINARY.

I have found some questions that talking it is not allowed to call outside functions in kernel!

OPENCL:
[OpenCL - is it possible to invoke another function from within a kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196552/opencl-is-it-possible-to-invoke-another-function-from-within-a-kernel)

CUDA:
[CUDA External calls not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994005/cuda-external-calls-not-supported)

If I was not wrong that is one of the OPENCL/CUDA limitations:

OpenCL: https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/restrictions.html

CUDA: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#functions

Am I right? What is the reason behind of this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPU and GPU are completely different computer architectures with completely different instruction sets.  Programs written for one can't run on the other.

When you run a program on a GPU using CUDA or OpenCL, you're basically running it on a different computer.  It doesn't have access to all the resources that the host computer does:  it can't access the hard drive, or communicate on the network, or use any other services provided by the host operating system.  All the GPU code can do is modify data in memory.

`system("ngspice")` doesn't work because:

- `"ngspice"` is the name of a program on the hard drive, but the GPU can't interact with the hard drive, and
- even if it could, the program is compiled for the CPU and can't run on the GPU.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's completely meaningless. The system you are trying to invoke does not exist on a GPU. There are no external programs you can invoke on a GPU. It's completely meaningless to try to invoke a program or the shell through `system`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `system` in the GPU environment (like Puppy said). If you want to execute a `system` function based on a computational result of a kernel, you could write to an output variable from inside the kernel and use that in the host code to determine whether it should run a `system` call or not.

Comment: I need to execute this function 3000 times, and I thought I can to do this on GPU.